# How to run Workseet_Change event only if Target is manually selected?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim r1 As Range
Set r1 = Range("A1:B10")
If Intersect(Selection, r1) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub  ' how to write this line ?
MsgBox "323"
End Sub
```

I want the MsgBox only if I manually select and change some cell inside r1, not by running another code which changes this cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

In a `Module`, declare a `Public` variable

```
Public CodeChangingCells As Boolean
```

In all you Subs that can change relavent cells set this variable

```
Sub SubTahtChangesCells()

On Error GoTo EH

CodeChangingCells = True
Sheet1.[A1] = Sheet1.[A1] + 1

CleanUp:
On Error Resume Next
CodeChangingCells = False
Exit Sub
EH:
  ' Handle errors

GoTo CleanUp
End Sub
```

Test this variable in the `Cnage` event
Use `Target` rather than `Selection`

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim r1 As Range
    If Not CodeChangingCells Then
        Set r1 = Me.Range("A1:B10")
        If Intersect(Target, r1) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub  ' how to write this line ?
        MsgBox "323"
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

use a flag.

set `ImDoingTheUpdating=True` when you are in your routine, and back to `False` when finished.

That way, you can put `If ImDoingTheUpdating Then Exit Sub` into the Worksheet_Change event

Answer (score 2):

If you want to disable events when running code the normal practice is to use `Application.EnableEvents = false`

so based on your example code, the second sub will not fire the change event when changing cells.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim r1 As Range
Set r1 = Sheet1.Range("A1:B10")
If Intersect(Selection, r1) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub  ' how to write this line ?
MsgBox "323"
End Sub

Sub EventsWillFire()
    'Worksheet_Change will fire
    Sheet1.Range("A1:B10").ClearContents
End Sub

Sub EventsDisabled()
    'Worksheet_Change will NOT fire
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Sheet1.Range("A1:B10").ClearContents
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

The only thing to be aware of is that if you exit code whilst debugging or don't handle errors properly then Application.EnableEvents may be in state FALSE and no events will fire. A quick way to re-enable them is to type `Application.EnableEvents = True` into the Immediate window of the debugger and hit return/enter.